# Viewmodel Initialize() not called after starting activity via intent

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, mvvmcross

I need to show a viewmodel/view without the previous navigationstack etc. The szenario is a logout which redirects to a fresh loginview. 

For this, I try to start a new activity with the ActivityFlags.ClearTask and ActivityFlags.NewTask to reset navigation etc. My viewpresenter, which inherits from MvxAppCompatViewPresenter, creates the Intent from a viewmodel-request, adds the needed activity flags and starts it.

The activity and the related viewmodel are created and navigated to, but the Initialize()-method on the viewmmodel is never called. 

The project uses mvvmcross 5.4.2 currently.

Example code:

```
var intent = base.CreateIntentForRequest(request);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

base.ShowIntent(intent);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Initialize` method was only called when using the `MvxNavigationService`until MvvmCross 5.5. Either update to that so it is fixed, or use the `MvxNavigationService`.

More information is in the documentation.
https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle#tombstoning-saving-and-restoring-the-viewmodels-state